# $a^n-1$ and $b^n-1$ have the same set of prime factors for each $n\in\Bbb{Z}^+$, show that $a=b$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $a,b$ be two positive integers, if $a^n-1$ and $b^n-1$ have the same set of prime factors for each $n\in\Bbb{Z}^+$, then $a=b$.

It seems to be not hard, but I have no idea. Any hint is welcome.

Edit: As the comment points out, it is probably not easy. I thought it is easy because it is kind of intuitively correct. I tried to study the Zsigomondy primes as $n$ increases, but it is not successful.

Comment: “It seems to be not hard”. I think this problem elementarily implies the N7 of the IMO Shortlist 2009. So... it probably isn’t easy.

Comment: @Mindlack I looked at the N7 of the IMO 2009 shortlist. I don't see how this problem implies it. For any $a\neq b$, we got some $n$ such that $a^n-1$ and $b^n-1$ has different set of prime factors, but it does not (at least not directly) imply that $(a^n-1)(b^n-1)$ is not a perfect square.

Comment: If $a,b$ are as in the N7: Assume there is some $n$ such that $a^n-1$ has a prime factor $p$ not dividing $b^n-1$. Then $a^n-1$ has an even $p$-adic valuation, as $(a^n-1)(b^n-1)$ is a square. So $(a^{pn}-1)(b^{pn}-1)$ also has an even $p$-adic valuation. But $b^{pn}-1=b^n-1$ mod $p$ so isn’t divisible by $p$, so the valuation of $a^{np}-1$ is even. But by LTE, the $p$-aduc valuation of $a^{np}-1$ is that of $a^n-1$ (which is even) plus one, so is odd. We get a contradiction, so by the problem of the OP $a=b$. That’s why I wrote “elementarily implies” instead of “obviously implies”.

Comment: In any event @MathEric this is quite a good problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition that $a^n-1$ and $b^n-1$ have the same prime factors for every $n$ is equivalent to $a$ and $b$ having the same order mod $p$ for every $p$. Equivalently, for every positive integer $k$ and every prime $p$, $a$ is a $k$-th power mod $p$ if and only if $b$ is a $k$-th power mod $p$. I will argue that for fixed $a\neq b$ and every sufficiently large prime value of $k$, there is a positive proportion of primes $p$ for which $a$ is a $k$-th power mod $p$ but $b$ is not.

Suppose $2\leq a< b$. Let $q>b$ be a prime, and consider the field $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[q]{a},\sqrt[q]{b},\zeta_q)$, where $\zeta_q$ is a primitive $q$-th root of unity. Then
$$
G:=\operatorname{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})\cong \mathbb{F}_q^\times \ltimes\left(\mathbb{F}_q\times\mathbb{F}_q\right).
$$
Then $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[q]{a})$ is the fixed field of $H_1:=\mathbb{F}_q^\times \ltimes\left(\{0\}\times\mathbb{F}_q\right)$, and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[q]{b})$ is the fixed field of $H_2:=\mathbb{F}_q^\times \ltimes\left(\mathbb{F}_q\times \{0\}\right)$. If $p$ is a rational prime coprime to $a$, $b$, and $q$, then $a$ is a $q$-th power mod $p$ if and only if the Frobenius conjugacy class of $p$ in $G$ intersects $H_1$, and $b$ is a $q$-th power mod $p$ if and only if the Frobenius conjugacy class of $p$ in $G$ intersects $H_2$. Now, by the Chebotarev density theory, there exist a positive proportion of primes $p$ whose Frobenius conjugacy class contains $(1,0,1)\in G$. Then the conjugacy class intersects $H_1$ but not $H_2$, so for such $p$, $a$ is a $q$-th power mod $p$ but $b$ is not.

Comment: Nice idea, but could you please detail the computation of the Galois group? It seems to fail for instance when $b$ is a power of $a$ (in this case, of course, we can solve the problem through other means, but perhaps there are other cases where the group isn’t this large)...